# Replace another dropdown while the value in one drop down selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxes with ids dd1,dd2. While selecting a value from select box 1 the value in seelct box 2 should be replaced in jquery. The following is not worked. What mistake I am doing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<head>
<script>
function change(){
alert("Hi");
$('dd2').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="5">5</option>') ;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="dd1" onchange=change()>
<option>1<option>
<option>2<option>
<option>3<option>
<option>4<option>
</select>

<select id="dd2">
  <option>A<option>
  <option>B<option>
  <option>C<option>
  <option>D<option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you require. For example, if I choose `1` from the first select, should that item be removed and placed in the second select to give `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `1`? Should it be copied? What ordering? Also note that you're including three copies of the same version of jQuery and your id selector is missing the preceding `#`

Comment: your first script tag has no end tag, and all scripts should be either into head or body section.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `#` in your Jquery selector for an ID: `$('#dd2')...`

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5g3p0t5/